# Does In app-billing work if app is not downloaded from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I'm considering to distribute an app on market that are different from google play official market.

If an user download the app from a third parts website will the in-app purchasement works or no?

Certainly the user must have Google Play installed on the device and apps published on Google Play, but I haven't understood if is not stricly needed to download the apk from Google Play store for the in-app purchase functioning.

Could someone clarify this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements:

- app would be published at Google Play and configured properly all in-app billing properties there.
- user must have installed Google Play Services at its device; in-app billing won't work without it.

User can download *same* apk form other places and everything will work there. Same means that apk would be same as you will upload to Google Play (application id, version, sign, etc.)